# How do you determine whether you can us LNAV/VNAV minima on an RNAV approach?

Tags: faa-regulations, iaps, terps

If we look at this approach plate it has

- LPV DA
- LNAV / VNAV DA
- LNAV MDA
- CIRCLING

I understand that if you have WAAS you can shoot the approach to LPV DA minimums. If you have only a GPS with a DME providing lateral navigation you can shoot the LNAV MDA. If you are more than 30 degrees off centerline you shoot the circling. So my question is, how can you shoot the LNAV / VNAV DA on a non-precision GPS approach? Does this require a special GPS that has vertical guidance?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between LNAV/VNAV and LPV minimums on an RNAV approach?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/what-is-the-difference-between-lnav-vnav-and-lpv-minimums-on-an-rnav-approach)

Answer (score 5):

The STC documentation provided with the GPS / FMS installation will indicate the type of minima it can go down to.

Typically, GA aircraft like a Garmin 430/530 will only be certified down to LNAV minima.

Business type aircraft with FMS's may be certified to LNAV/VNAV minima.  These installations use a barometric altitude input to calculate a pseudo glidepath to be displayed.

Comment: I would like to add that you can turn waas off in a garmin 430 and that's another way you could know.  The other way is fly the approach in vfr and if it says LPV on the GPS then you have it.  If your renting ask the people you are renting from. I can only assume there's a higher cost for updates(or miantance I guess) with WAAS so find out who pays the bills.

Comment: This answer is misleading, many 430/530 units can do LPV, you just need WAAS.