# In simple terms, what are LNAV, VNAV, and Baro-VNAV approaches?

Tags: terminology, approach, instrument-procedures

In simple words, what are LNAV, VNAV, and BARO-NAV?

Are they all precision approaches and will they cancel the traditional approaches?

Comment: Related: [What is “required navigation performance” or “RNP”?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25873/what-is-required-navigation-performance-or-rnp). See also [this Boeing document](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_2_08/AERO_Q208_article3.pdf).

Comment: Also related: [What is the difference between LNAV/VNAV and LPV minimums on an RNAV approach?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1087/69) and [Is LPV considered a precision approach?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6341/69).